# Is there any way to fully control my android phone by PC using lan network?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to control my android phone from a way out!I need to see my phone's screen.I want use my access point modem to perform this.
I have search the net but could not find a proper answer.
Is there any solution?

Thanks.

Sorry if the question tag may be wrong.

Comment: The tags are fine, just the wrong website :)  Try XDA Devs

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are seeking dev related instructions or just need an app which does what you want.

If the latter you should check this forum instead: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Some apps I know which does this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unicorntoast.mrroboto.android

https://www.xda-developers.com/android/app-review-remotely-control-your-android-device-with-teamviewer-xda-developer-tv/

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that android supports this out of the box, as that would be a security hole.

You might be able to get some rdp Service installed, as android is a linux distribution, but I it might drain your battery.

try this:
http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/market/apps/app/com.xtralogic.android.rdpclient/Remote-Desktop-Client